# Basic class instances knowledge

Tags: c#, oop

I am getting a little confused about class instances and I tried to search the internet for my specific question but I could not find an answer.

Assume I have a parent class `Screen` and child classes `GameplayScreen` and `SettingsScreen`.

If inside my main game class I do the following:

```
Screen currentScreen = new Screen();
```

Then each time the user wants to change screen:

```
if (gameplay) 
    currentScreen = new GameplayScreen(); 
else 
    currentScreen = new SettingsScreen();
```

Is this a good approach considering performance? Is there a better way to do this like unloading resources?

Comment: The answer to this is **fundamentally different** for C++ and C#, since the two languages are *nothing alike* in this regard (in fact, they are nothing alike in general). Please decide on one.

Comment: Where do you have the `if (gameplay)...` code? Something like a MainGeneralScreen?

Comment: Yes it is located in the main game class

Comment: I don't understand, why are even using `new Screen()`? Or does that represent some third kind of screen (maybe a blank one)?

Comment: Screen is the parent class and yes it is a blank screen

Comment: I think the current design isn't too bad. You just need to make method RefreshScreen and call it whenever you change the currentScreen to refresh the display, to view the new screen and hide the other one.

Comment: So, if the user kept jumping between screens, will this accumulate data in the heap? or does initiating a new class removes the old data?

Comment: It depends on how you do it. I would instantiate both screens and keep them in private members. When the user changes the screen, it only replaces the currentScreen to point into the appropriate already-instantiated window (and refreshes view).

Comment: To make sure I am understanding correctly, your approach means that the heap will contain all screens all the time and I just switch between them when displaying/updating?

Comment: Yes, but as @svick said, and I agree with him, it really depends on what the screens are actually all about, and how you want them to switch. I would imagine that the settings screen will open up in front of the gameplay screen and disable it as long as it is open, but it doesn't sound like that is what it does, so these are different behaviors, and each situations deserves a new look on the design and different considerations to take.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12070/discussion-between-baracat-and-yorye-nathan)

Answer (score 2):

The answer could depend on what kind of resources do the `Screen` child types hold, whether their initialization takes a long time and whether they hold a lot of resources (or a “precious” resource).

But the most likely answer is that your code is just fine, and that you shouldn't worry about creating new object when a screen changes (and let the garbage collector take care of the old one).

Comment: Do you suggest any alternative approach to manage multiple screens?

Comment: Like I said, that depends entirely on the specific situation. Some alternatives like using `Dispose()` or keeping the screens in fields might make sense, but it's hard to tell without knowing anything about the screens.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on keeping the screens in fields?